# :hover pseudoclass selector in email for gmail

Tags: javascript, css, email, gmail, pseudo-class

I am sending some mail from my `php` script.

it has structure like:

```
<style type="text/css">
.elements{
/*its CSS*/
}
.elements:hover{
/* Hoverd CSS changes background and color*/
}
</style>
<center>
Actual Mail Body <a class="elements" href="URL">Element</a>
<center>
```

and this works fine in all mail clients except `gmail`.
So a quick `SO` search lead me to: [HTML formatted email not showing up at all in Gmail but is in other mail clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224195/html-formatted-email-not-showing-up-at-all-in-gmail-but-is-in-other-mail-clients)

and I came to know that `gmail` doesn't support `<style>` but supports `inline-style`.

So I tried this:

```
<center>
Actual Mail Body <a class="elements" href="URL" style="it's style here">Element</a>
<center>
```

But now my problem is `:hover` pseudoclass can't be converted to `inline-style`, So I tried to mimic it with `JavaScript` as:

```
<center>
Actual Mail Body <a class="elements" href="URL" 
OnMouseOver="this.style.background='#ddeeff';this.style['color']='#555555';"
onmouseout="back-to-original-css">Element</a>
<center>
```

But that ain't helped me.

So **is there any way to make `:hover` pseudo class work in `gmail` mail client?**

Also I don't think this is impossible (have a look at `g+'s` mail in your `gmail` account. They can send such mails.)

Any thoughts, ideas, suggestion are welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: If gmail is sending them, did you look at the email with chrome dev tools to see how they're doing it?

Comment: @Jeff, I tried but I was unable to point out the code. Also I thinnk they support `javascript` for `g+`'s mails, coz it can open `popup`, `aria-label`, can `add freinds to your circle` without going to `g+`'s site.

Comment: It looks like JavaScript is injecting the styles. You may be able to do the same. This SO might get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15506705/2055676

Answer (score 10):

Well there are a lot of controversy on the subject but, here is what I found. **Prepare for a wall of text**. It appears you can use a workaround to make `<style>` work, as stated [here](http://freshinbox.com/blog/gmail-supports-style-sort-of/).

Here are the actual quotes:

> Gmail strips class and id attributes from all elements but leaves some
>   other attributes intact: style, title, lang, width, height, alt, href.
>
> Since href and alt are not technically legal attributes for divs I
>   decided not to use them even though you could if you wanted to. A
>   prime candidate would be title – however title comes with one
>   side-effect – when the user hovers the cursor over the element, the
>   title would be visible.
>
> I chose the lang attribute because it is a universal attribute (valid
>   for all elements) that is not visible when hovered over. Naturally
>   we’re not using this attribute for its intended purpose – but there’s
>   a technical exception in the HTML specifications that allow us to use
>   it this way. By pre-pending the attribute value with an “x-”, this
>   signifies that the lang attribute is not meant to be meaningful to the
>   client and as far as I know, no email client currently processes the
>   lang attribute anyways.
>
> **Breakdown**
>
> Here’s a total breakdown of all the styles I’ve tried and found
>   working in Gmail:
>
> ```
> The following works in Gmail:
> * E[foo]
> * E[foo="bar"]
> * E[foo~="bar"]
> * E[foo^="bar"]
> * E[foo*="bar"]
> * E[foo$="bar"]
> * E:hover
> * E:link
> * E:visited
> * E:active
>
> E F
> E > F
> E + F
> E ~ F
> ```

Summary of how Gmail processes CSS in a style tag (in the  of the email).

```
.divbox {..}  //Allowed but pointless - Gmail strips class attributes from elements
#divbox {..}  //Allowed but pointless - Gmail strips id attributes from elements

[class~="divbox"] {...} //Removed by Gmail
* [class~="divbox"] {...} //Allowed but pointless - No class attributes

div {...} //Allowed but too generic to be useful
div:hover {...} //Removed by gmail. No pseudo class support? Not so fast!
* div:hover {...} //Allowed! Interesting…

* [lang~="x-divbox"] {...} //Allowed! Now we’re talking

* [lang~="x-divbox"]:hover {...} //Allowed! Magic! :)
```

Disclaimer: The article is not written by me, and I take no credit for it.

### EDIT:

I tested it it works on both gmail and outlook (hotmail).

The code I used:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* [title="divbox"]:hover{
    background-color: green !important;
    color: white;
}

.blinking:hover{
    background-color: green !important;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="blinking" title="divbox" style="padding:10px;width:100px;height:40px;
  background-color:#eeeeee;">Divbox Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: The `blinking` class is for hotmail, since it doesn't display the gmail workaround.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time in solving this. But gmail is stripping `<style>` tags from `<head>` too. So this didn't helped me.

Comment: @VedantTerkarI just tested it. It works. Gmail strips only SOME styles as mentioned in the article.

Comment: Gmail strips `<style>` tags for domains hosted via Google for Work, if they are on the "Standard Release" track. @gmail.com addresses and Google for Work domains on the "Rapid Release" track will keep the style tags.