# Changing link color/css in Mailchimp email in gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, mailchimp

So I'm having an odd issue while setting up my RSS driven campaign in Mailchimp.

In an area in my template, I'm pulling in an excerpt from my post that could possibly have a link in it.

Let's say for example this is what a snippet of the code looks like in my template:

```
<div class="post-excerpt">
    *|RSSITEM:DESCRIPTION|*
</div>
```

Which for example lets say when the email is generated and sent the source looks like this:

```
<div class="post-excerpt">
    Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.example.com">dolor</a> sit amet.
</div>
```

Obviously I cannot add any inline css to that link, because it's getting generated by Mailchimp. But I'm adding CSS in my template like this:

```
.post-excerpt a { color:pink; text-decoration:none; }
```

And I also have Mailchimp's "Automatic CSS Inliner" setting turned **on**. This however doesn't seem to be moving my CSS to the links that get generated by `*|RSSITEM:DESCRIPTION|*`.

For some reason, in gmail on desktop, links appearing within `.post-excerpt` are still appearing default blue and underlined. On my iPhone, they are pink without any text decoration, as they should be.

Any idea on how to get the links in this area to appear the way I need them to?

Thank you.

Comment: Gmail really sucks in styling elements using `<style>`, Here is Useful link: http://freshinbox.com/blog/gmail-supports-style-sort-of/

Comment: From what I'm experiencing, it's stripping out `<style>` tags.

Comment: Yeah! you're correct, The same was happening with me(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812613/hover-pseudoclass-selector-in-email-for-gmail), but i was able to add inline styling.

Answer (score 1):

**Gmail strips out** all of the style **information in the header** (anything in the `<head>` part of the document including `<style>`).

Gmail app also does this.  This is the main reason you can't create responsive emails for Gmail.

Obviously as you correctly state, you cannot put an inline link due to the link being imported through your RSS feed.

However, have you considered making the whole description a link?  I don't know if it will work but it's worth a try.  It might even improve click through rates.

```
<a href="*|RSSITEM:URL|*" style="text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;">*|RSSITEM:DESCRIPTION|*</a>
```

As a further thought you could also consider putting `<style> CSS goes here </style>` in your body at the bottom of your email.